# How to run `clear_console` in Bash when TMOUT happens?

Tags: bash, timeout

How do I tell Bash to run a `clear_console` when the session is closed because of TMOUT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trap the `EXIT` event.  It works also for interactive shells.

```
trap clear_console EXIT
TMOUT=10
```

Comment: The problem is trap also runs when manual termination happens.  For example when user types exit command in the shell.  Any way to trap only the TMOUT exit?